# how to clear previous variable from future function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

To better explain my question i created [simplified jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6gX8z/4/).
When selecting "a array" from dropdown menu and then selecting "b array" and scrolling down first 5 elements are loaded from "b array" then all unloaded elements from "a array" and only then rest of "b array" but instead only "b array" elements should show up.
My question is how to get rid of previously selected array elements getting loaded in div?

**EDITED:**
This is my first attempt to write something in javascript so sorry everyone for eye burning from looking at my code and thanks for help - @ThiefMaster suggested unbind works for me

Comment: fyi, `.attr("value")` is bad, use `.val()` instead. And please get rid of **every single damn `eval`** in your code. it's horrible. put those arrays in an object instead of making them separate global variables!

Comment: I had a "coding horror" moment looking at your fiddle. :p

Comment: Not sure I get this at all, but you're loading more values in the scroll function, why not just remove that then [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6gX8z/6/) ????

Comment: @adeneo: He wants infinite scrolling.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - oooh, not easy to see from that fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the old `scroll` events stay bound. You need to unbind them.

A quick fix would be using

```
$("#objects").unbind('scroll').scroll(function() {
```

instead of

```
$("#objects").scroll(function() {
```

Demo (also removed the `eval` crap): http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/6gX8z/8/